# How do I specialize a member function of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

```
template<typename _TChar>
struct simplestring
{
    void show_tstring()
    {
        throw "no implement";
    }

    void simplestring<char>::show_tstring()
    {
        cout << "char string\n";
    }

    void simplestring<wchar_t>::show_tstring()
    {
        cout << "wchar_t string\n";
    }
};


void test()
{
    simplestring<char> s;
    s.show_tstring();
}
```

I want to specialize the member function show_tstring of simplestring. When _TChar is char output "char string\n" and when _TChar is wchar_t output "wchar_t string\n". Otherwise throw an exception.

It doesn't compile with error message:

> Error C2535   'void simplestring<_TChar>::show_tstring(void)': member
> function already defined or declared

I also tried to put the function outside the class,

```
void simplestring<char>::show_tstring()
{
    cout << "char string\n";
}
```

Compilation failed with

> Error C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support
> default-int   ForTest D:\test\ForTest\ForTest\templateTest.h  848

Comment: You forgot to mention the problem with the shown code.

Comment: @cigien, it doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, but then you need to show the error message.

Comment: How exactly "it doesn't compile"? What happens? If you call your auto mechanic and tell them "my car doesn't move", and nothing more, do you think you'll get helpful tips on fixing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the specializations outside the class body:

```
template<typename _TChar>
struct simplestring
{
    void show_tstring()
    {
        throw "no implement";
    }
};

template<>
void simplestring<char>::show_tstring()
{
    std::cout << "char string\n";
}

template<>
void simplestring<wchar_t>::show_tstring()
{
    std::cout << "wchar_t string\n";
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/6n8E51

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had just tried `template<char> void simplestring::show_tstring()` outside the class, one step behind the correct one :D.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, in C++17, you might do:

```
template <typename Char>
struct simplestring
{
    void show_tstring() const
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Char, char>) {
            std::cout << "char string\n";
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Char, wchar_t>) {
            std::cout << "wchar_t string\n";
        } else {
            throw "no implement";
        }
    }
};
```

In C++20, you might do:

```
template <typename Char>
struct simplestring
{
    void show_tstring() const requires (std::is_same_v<Char, char>)
    {
        std::cout << "char string\n";
    }
    void show_tstring() const requires (std::is_same_v<Char, wchar_t>)
    {
        std::cout << "wchar_t string\n";
    }
    // nothing for other (instead of exception)
};
```